# Python selenium get element values from opened model gives unopened models values

Tags: python, selenium, loops, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing a small issue while try to get values from a web page using python and Selenium. First of all I must say, the person who wrote the webpage is not written using the best way.
There are few models in the html file and I'm trying to get values from the currently opened one.

```
for modal in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("modal"):
    if modal.value_of_css_property("display") == "block":
        location = modal.find_element_by_tag_name("p").get_attribute("textContent")
        phValue = modal.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tr[3]//td[2]").find_element_by_tag_name("p").get_attribute("textContent")

        print(location) // giving me the correct value
        print(phValue)  // giving me the wrong value
```

As you can see here I'm getting all the modals and try to get the active modal using the display css property. then I'm getting the active modal's paragraph tag value as location. It is working as I need and giving me the paragraph  tag value of the currently opened modal. Every modal has a table, inside the table, I'm getting some values. But phValue gives me the value of currently UNOPENED model's values instead of the Opened one. any Idea how to fix this?

PS- The wrong value is in the First model and it is not opened currently.

Thanks for the help fellas.

Below will be the HTML part of one of the modals. There are lot of modals in the file same as this. (Some of the data are in Unicode.)

```
<div id="Adayalachchena04" class="modal">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" style="color:red">&times;</span>
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><b>ගොවිජන සේවා බල ප්&zwj;රදේශ අනුව පොහොර නිර්දේශ භාවිතයේදී සැලකිය යුතු කරුණු</b></span></h4>
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h4>
            <p>ප&zwj;්&zwj;රාදේශීය ලේකම් කොට්ඨාශය - අඩයාලච්චේන<br />ග&zwj;්&zwj;රාම නිලධාරි වසම - අඩයාලච්චේන 04</p>
            <table class="table-responsive" style="height: 179px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
               <tbody>
                  <tr style="height: 35px;">
                     <td style="height: 35px;" colspan="6">
                        <p style="text-align: center;">පස් පරීක්ෂණ ප&zwj;්&zwj;රතිඵල</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="height: 48.6667px;">
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD">පරාමිතිය</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD">පී. එච්. අගය</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD"> විද්&zwj;යුත් 
                           සන්නායකතාවය </br>
                           ඩෙසි සී / මී
                        </p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD">පොස්පරස් කිලෝ 
                           ග&zwj;්&zwj;රෑමයට <br />
                           මිලි ග&zwj;්&zwj;රෑම්
                        </p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD">පොටෑසියම්  කිලෝ 
                           ග&zwj;්&zwj;රෑමයට </br>
                           මිලි ග&zwj;්&zwj;රෑම් 
                        </p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 48.6667px;">
                        <p class="textD">කාබනික 
                           ද්&zwj;රව්&zwj;ය 
                        </p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="height: 35px;">
                     <td style="height: 70px;" rowspan="2">පසේ තත්වය</td>
                     <td style="height: 35px;">
                        <p>5.0</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 35px;">
                        <p>0.070</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 35px;">
                        <p>46.0</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 35px;">
                        <p>265.0</p>
                     </td>
                     <td style="height: 35px;">
                        <p>3.4</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>    
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you add the HTML snippet?

Comment: @AlinStelian, Hi thanks for the reply. I have just added the html part to original post. Please have a look. thanks

Comment: I don't see any class name called "modal" but there is "modal-content", try that.

Comment: @AlinStelian Sorry mate, I missed the main div. Please check now. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get that element, you can use CSS selector instead of XPath

```
    phValue = modal.find_element_by_css_selector("table tbody tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) p").get_attribute("textContent")
```

I cannot test cause I don't have the app link.

Comment: OMG. It is working mate. Thanks. Can you please tell me, why we can't use xpath?

Comment: my guess is that XPATH doesn't know which modal you want explicitly so it will take whatever string matches first the DOM, also CSS is more efficient then XPath.